# How can I create NSDocument (subclass) instances for a viewer-oriented app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdocument

I'm trying out Cocoa (on OS X Mavericks) with a NSDocument-oriented app with a (planned) WebKit control.  I noticed that the "New" menu command is disabled if all the document types are Viewer or Other.  I'm making a web browser, so the app shouldn't be an Editor for anything, yet that's what I need to enable the New command.

I guess I need to override something, but where?  The obvious candidates are the NSDocument subclass, a NSDocumentController subclass, or an application delegate.  The first one is the only one I actually have so far (i.e. included by Xcode's default code), but it doesn't seem appropriate for NSDocument instances to create new ones.  So I would have to create a NSDocumentController or NSApplicationDelgate subclass to do this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much of a newbie that I didn't completely RTFM.

The new-document command is handled by `NSDocumentController`. That class has a `defaultType` method that's used to determine which type a new document should be.  By default it chooses the first type in the (static) list of document types that is set to "Editor" mode.  It returns `nil` otherwise (i.e. Viewer and Utility apps).

A non-editing app can gain new documents by creating a subclass of `NSDocumentController` that at least overrides `defaultType` to return a non-`nil` string describing the document type for new documents.  I used a MIME type, but I guess UTIs (and maybe extensions) also work.

But there's a new problem: your `NSDocumentController` won't be created by default; the default App setup ignores the class and makes a `NSDocumentController` object anyway.  There's supposedly two ways around this: put an object of your subclass into the app's first NIB, the one with the main menu bar; or directly set the document-controller attribute to a new object of your subclass in one of the initialization methods of the application delegate.  (Since the default document-based project templates don't include an application delegate class, you have to create that too.)

But I heard that either method is uncertain; if any previous part of application startup touches the NSDocument system, a default document-controller will be created and block out your object.  Are there any Cocoa gurus out there that know where to put a custom `NSDocumentController` subclass object so it can't get pre-empted by a default document-controller?

...

I tried putting what I said in the third paragraph to work, but it doesn't.  I keep getting "*Date* *Time* *MyApp*[*Number1*:*Number2*] The *XXX* type doesn't map to any NSDocumentClass." from the NSLog debug screen, where *XXX* is the string I return from `defaultType`.  Tried both MIME types and UTIs.  I'm stumped for the moment.

Comment: Since the smarts of my app are in the WebKit control, I gave up on the `NSDocument` architecture and ripped it out. (The dependencies between them are the wrong way.) I recently added an `NSDocumentController` subclass to get control of the "Open Recent" menu back.